# Error [render methods should be a pure function of props and state] during state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I was using react-nprogress, I get the following problem in my console:

[image]

Here's my code:

```js
const NTTracker = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(NTTrackerContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Route
          render={({ location }) => (
            <>
              <Progress isAnimating={isLoading} key={location.key} />
              <TransitionGroup className="body-dom">
                <CSSTransition
                  classNames="fade"
                  key={location.key}
                  onEnter={() => {setIsLoading(true)}}
                  onEntered={() => {setIsLoading(false)}}
                  timeout={450}
                  in={true}
                >
                  <Switch location={location}>
                    <Route exact path="/"><h1>Home</h1></Route>
                    // code for Login and APIHome below
                    <Route exact path="/accounts/login"><Login/></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/api/:teamname"><APIHome/></Route>
                    <Route exact path="*" component={NoMatch} />
                  </Switch>
                </CSSTransition>
              </TransitionGroup>
              <Footer/>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};
```

Please note that `NTTracker` is wrapped in a context provider.

```js
return (
  <NTTrackerContextProvider initState={initialState}>
    <NTTracker/>
  </NTTrackerContextProvider>
)
```

This is pretty similar (if not the same) with the [demo usage](https://github.com/tanem/react-nprogress/tree/master/examples/react-router). The problem is that nprogress seems unable to handle redirections with state change correctly, per the output above.

More specifically, the error occurred with these steps:

1. the user clicks "log out," at URL `/api/team1` and the state of the application is changed (`state.user.authenticated` changed from `true` to `false`).
2. when the state is changed, the code below detects the change and redirects the user to `/accounts/login`
3. when the page completed the redirection, the error above occurred.

The URL `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/team1` is defined as:

```js
function APIHome() {
  if (!state.user.authenticated) history.push("/accounts/login");
  // ...
}
```

The redirected URL `http://127.0.0.1:3000/accounts/login` is defined as:

```js
function Profile() {
  // if you need anything in here, please let me know
```

My description and logging may not be exactly accurate. If there are any inquiries or potential problems in my error description, please comment below.

Unfortunately, I can't put this into a sandbox because it will essentially be hosting the entire project as the bug depends on the change of state (where the data are retrieved from a separate backend server).

Thanks in advance.